# Using iTextpdf version 5.5 and itext-asian 5.2 kanji charachter  is not displaying on PDF

Tags: java, fonts, itext, cjk

Creating PDF using

- iTextpdf version 5.5.13.3
- itext-asian 5.2.0

Only kanji character  is not displayed,
but all other Japanese characters are displayed on created PDF.

#### Code

Used to set the BaseFont

```
BaseFont bfJapanese = BaseFont.createFont(
  AsianFontMapper.JapaneseFont_Min,
  AsianFontMapper.JapaneseEncoding_H,
  BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED
);
```

Is there any other way to set the Japanese fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Creating a font by name and encoding

You called the method `BaseFont.createFont(String name, String encoding, boolean embedded)` correctly.

The `AsianFontMapper` class has those constants for 2 font names and 4 encodings:

```
// font names
    public static final String JapaneseFont_Go = "HeiseiKakuGo-W5";
    public static final String JapaneseFont_Min = "HeiseiMin-W3";
// encodings
    public static final String JapaneseEncoding_H = "UniJIS-UCS2-H";
    public static final String JapaneseEncoding_V = "UniJIS-UCS2-V";
    public static final String JapaneseEncoding_HW_H = "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H";
    public static final String JapaneseEncoding_HW_V = "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-V";
```

The [Kanji character  for "earth"](https://www.kanshudo.com/kanji/%F0%A0%AE%B7) should be supported by above Japanese fonts of *Heisei* family and all of those encodings.

#### Japanese font must be present on your system

Make sure that they are available the system creating and viewing the PDF.

When using `embedded = false` to keep the PDF-size small, they must also been present on the viewing system.

See Wikipedia article: *List of CJK fonts*, especially the table for [Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts#Japanese_2):

- Adobe provides the above named [`Heisei Mincho`](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/heisei-mincho-std) font-family and [`Heisei Kaku Gothic`](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/heisei-kaku-gothic-std).
- Microsoft supports the Japanese script with font-families like [`SimHei`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/simhei?source=recommendations) or [`SimSun`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/simsun).
- From Google you can download [Japanese fonts, e.g. the `Noto` family](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=japanese&noto.script=Jpan)

Comment: Hi,
I used following setting and now PDF is displaying the kanji charachter

`BaseFont bfJapanese = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\msmincho.ttc,0", 
     BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`
Thanks